# How to execute some event if RN has been killed?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

Not sure if I understand correctly but according to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently)

> Deliver silent notifications and wake up your app in the background on the user's device.

It sounded to me that it's possible to perform some action even if the app has been killed.

Currently I'm using `OneSignal` as below:

```
OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);

onReceived(store, notification) {
  store.dispatch(receivedNotification({ notification }));
}
```

However the above will only be able to dispatch action if the app is in background or foreground, but once the app been killed, despite receiving notification successfully, `onReceived` event will not be fired.

So my question is whether is it possible to "wake" my RN app in the background and dispatch a redux action?

Answer (score -1):

There is no event that you can catch before app is killed. You also cannot prevent the user from killing your app. And once it is killed you cannot 'wake' it up, as your code is not running. You can only do such tasks when the app is in the background/foreground.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible you can execute some event if RN has been killed.
now the question is how basically I am also using react-native and I have got some challenges also, I also want to execute some event if RN has been killed, but I did not get any answer actually my concern is to open an app which can and show a call screen when calling notification is received so I dig a lot and I found a solution,
first I created a bridge connection between javascript to java and then write a wakeful service which gets called every time when we receive notification and then I call my background intent service and in this service I wake up my activity and set some flags which help me to open screen when screen is lock depends on the conditions

// receiver Service //

```
public class MessagingService extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseService";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(!isAppOnForeground(context)));


    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        if (!isAppOnForeground((context))) {
            //This get called every time you receive notification
        }
    }
}

private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (appProcesses == null) {
        return false;
    }
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
        if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Do u mind to share some sample code on this matter cause I don't have any of the native knowledges

Comment: @Isaac see this

Comment: Thank you very much for your code sample. I am still not quite sure about how we link JS to Android in the above code sample. Is your `onReceive` event expecting to override my `onReceived` event from JS?

Comment: what are your intentions? what you wanted to create ?

Comment: Note: please use android studio for better understanding, first you have to create brige and the easy way to create brige use peggys package react-native-createbridge

Comment: My intention is to receive a silent notification from server, then dispatch a redux action, in silent. This has been done while app is in foreground/background but not when app has been killed

Comment: Basically, I waked up my activity first when I receive notification and then I sent an event to react-native to accept and decline a call, read this article it will help you and please upvote